# My UI gets distorted when I run it through my device(USB debugging) but works fine on my AVD

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have built a layout in android studio and It appears the same on my AVD but not when i run it in my device. 
Here's the xml of my layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context=".toggled_meditate"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/togglemeditate"
    android:layout_width="197dp"
    android:layout_height="244dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="197dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="197dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="281dp"
    android:background="@drawable/togglebutton"
    android:transitionName="toggle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/togglehome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/actionscreen"
    android:transitionName="imageTransition" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my output in android studio,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15CQW.jpg)

Here's my output when i run it in my Galaxy S9,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4hlS.jpg)

I have implemented layouts in various densities and sizes(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi.normal,large,x-large.. etc) but still the result is the same, What am I doing wrong here?

ps-my home screen-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX9CI.png)

Comment: What is the image resolution?

Comment: depends, i have imported the background images from adobe XD therefore I have different resolutions for the same image according to their density in seperate folders  (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-mdpi and so on)

Comment: What is the reason for setting fixed dp for button height and width? dp value is different for different device.

Comment: Because I wanted to give it a more aesthetic look, this activity is called from a main home screen because i wanted to give it a enlarging animation, I have 3 more activities like this for 3 more buttons and if i give wrap content it would creates various button sizes loosing it's aesthetic effect, i'll attach a snap of my home screen to help you better understand

Comment: Then use dimens.xml to map out the dp values for various screen size. Also replace background with src in imageview. use scaleType to resize image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), you could avoid use all those fixed size dimensions on your views and by that make your layout responsive.

Here is an example of using `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[12]" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Notice that I am using this attributes:

```
 app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
```

To decide what size my view should be in percents (and not in fixed-size) according to the screen size. This will make sure that my layout is responsive to all screen size.

Comment: this code results in a white blank screen when i run it on my AVD, but appears fine on my design preview. Also the blank screen is responsive i can trigger intents with the button by blind guessing its position and tapping on it.

Comment: Did you changed ` tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[12]"` into something like ` android:background="@drawable/togglebutton`? because `tools` will only affect your preview and not the actual devices.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the cause, try to remove any `tools` attributes that you may have there and give your views your wanted background

Comment: I didn't notice, my bad, this fixed my problem,thanks alot :)

Comment: Sure, if that helped please accept the answer so it can help other developers with the same problem